# Just plugging the USB with OS in it doesn't make the RPI3B+ boot

Tags: pi-3b+

Flashed RetroPi OS into a flash disk. I plug it to the nearest USB slot to the board and the Ethernet. When I connect the power cable and the hdmi, it doesn't boot. I can't test if my Pi still works with a SD card because the SD Card slot's metal lid fell off. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you read and followed the manual on USB boot? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md

Comment: @Robert - "The Raspberry Pi 3B+ supports USB mass storage boot out of the box." - so, OP doesn't need to do anything

Comment: When you say "it doesn't boot" - anything at all on the screen? If not, perhaps when "he SD Card slot's metal lid fell off" there was more damage than you realise

Comment: @JaromandaX yes and no. I don't find it obvious that you have to wait up to 10 seconds for USB boot. Also it is important to know that there are USB sticks that simply don't work for USB boot.

Comment: @Robert - fair enough, I've never had a problem with a USB thumb drive - I have had an issue with a USB->Sata cable though - tip: avoid Sabrent products!!!

Comment: guys thanks for all the comments here. I guess I have no other option than fixing the reader's lid, eh?

Comment: What message  do you get on the screen? Just a blinking cursor in the upper left corner?

Comment: there is no signal going to the monitor. literally nothing happens